# Is there an inexpensive projection or transform $T$ so that $T(B)$ commutes with $AA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there an inexpensive projection or transform $T:\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ so that $T(B)$ commutes with $AA^T$ where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$?  I know that a projection is possible using the spectral decomposition $VDV^T=AA^T$ by letting $T(B) = V\mathrm{Diag}(\mathrm{diag}(V^TBV))V^T$ where $\mathrm{diag}$ extracts the diagonal and $\mathrm{Diag}$ forms a diagonal matrix.  This is the orthogonal projection.  That said, the spectral decomposition is expensive to compute for large matrices.  I'm looking for something like this that finds a somewhat close matrix to the original $B$, but where it commutes with $AA^T$.  By close, I mean that it doesn't have to be an orthogonal projection, but it shouldn't modify the matrix too dramatically if it's already close to commuting.

Comment: Please share with us the many notations $A,B,T,T(B),V,D$, what objects are involved (square matrices over some field like $\Bbb C$ maybe), and also which is your own effort to answer the question in the given generality.

Comment: A projection is always non expansive, isn't it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Ex**pen**sive, as in requiring a great deal of computational resources

Comment: @wyer33 There's always the zero and identity matrices

Comment: @wyer33 Also, it is incorrect to say that any projection $T(B)$ will necessarily be "close" to the original matrix $B$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann That's true, but the given projection is an orthogonal projection onto the eigenspace of $AA^T$.  I consider that close.  Mostly, it's not important that whatever transform follow a minimization procedure.

Comment: If that's the case, then it's not at all clear what you mean by "close". If you want the answer to be the result of a minimization procedure, then we need something (e.g. "distance") to minimize

Comment: @Ben Grossman Thanks for the two kind of corrections on expEnsive (I had written it like in french)... I wasn't thinking it terms of cost, but of distance reduction !!!

Comment: I've edited and clarified the question above.  Mostly, I'm looking for something that's non-trivial and is not going to excessively modify things.  We could simply just map a matrix to 0 or the identity and that would commute, but those also wipe out all of the information in the original matrix.  By close, it means it doesn't have to be an orthogonal projection, but it really shouldn't modify the matrix that much if it's already close to commuting.  Essentially, some kind of approximation to the orthogonal projection.